# How many Elements are in $(\mathbb{F}_{p})^{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> How many Elements are in the Vectorspace $(\mathbb{F}_{p})^{k}$

My Question isn't so much the Question I don't understand it in the first place. The Problem here is that I don't know over what Field the Vectorspace is and this is relevant because I already know $|V|=|F|^{dim(V)}$. So I have three explanations for this: My master has forgotten to give me a Field, Im supposed to do it in a general way or there is some natural Field over which the Vectorspace is. Can anybody help?

Comment: in general if $K$ is a field then a vector space $K^n$ is assumed to be over $K$, otherwise it must be explicitly stated

Comment: ok ty this helps

Comment: $\Bbb F_p$ is a specific field, namely $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. The other $F$ in your formula involving dimension is an arbitrary field but $V$ must be a $\dim V$ dimensional vector space over it.

Comment: This doesn't matter. $(\mathbb{F}_p)^k$ is a perfectly well-defined set as stated and the number of elements only depends on its nature as a set - it does not matter in which way you would view this as a vector space.